# While using selenium, UnreachableBrowserException:

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

What are the possible reasons for this Error

```
Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

Comment: what is the browser you are using? at what point does this error occurs? Please provide the stacktrace. This error is not caused because of element location, its something else. Please kill any other driver instances running in your background and then try. Thanks.

Comment: I'm Using Internet Explorer 10. I'm getting this error while trying to locate element from model popup. I have 'yes' and 'no' Button and i want to click yes button.

Comment: As u have already answered, its cause an instance of iedriver was in process in background, so anyhow u need to delete it and restart ur TC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code solved the issue

```
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM conhost.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hello Okuma.Scott, I updated the qsn. Does it reach to the quality and standard now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below locator

```
By.cssSelector("input[name='myButton']")
```

You've given wrong tag name (*select* instead of *input*) thats why it is throwing exception.